# "Left Join" like production of two collections in for-yield

Tags: scala, for-comprehension

I have two collections - `spells` and `charms`.
`charms` might be empty

I need to do `Magic` of the combinations of `spells` and `charms` and if `charms` is empty I need `Magic` of `spells` alone

For non-empty `charms` this works:

```scala
def hocusPocus(spells: Seq[String], charms: Seq[String]): Seq[Magic] = {
  for {
    spell <- spells
    charm <- charms
  } yield {
    new Magic(spell, Some(charm))
  }
}
```

This snippet is simple and clean, but for empty `charms` it makes no `Magic`

Is there any possibility to do some `Magic` from `spells` only in such a clear way, if one is out of `charms`?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of those cases where it is easier to use `flatMap` + `map` directly instead of using `for` *(IMHO)*
Also, it is a good use case to prefer a concrete collection like `List` over `Seq`

```scala
def hocusPocus(spells: List[String], charms: List[String]): List[Magic] =
  spells.flatMap { spell =>
    Magic(spell, None) :: charms.map(charm => Magic(spell, Some(charm)))
  }
```

Now, if you only need the `Magic` of spells alone if and only if charms is empty, you can do this:

```scala
def hocusPocus(spells: Seq[String], charms: Seq[String]): Seq[Magic] =
  if (charms.isEmpty)
    spells.map(spell => Magic(spell, None))
  else
    spells.flatMap { spell =>
      charms.map { charm =>
        Magic(spell, Some(charm))
      }
    }
```

Comment: this solution is what I was afraid of, but it looks like it is the only one applicable

Comment: @DenisKurochkin why are you afraid of this solution? What is wrong with it?

Comment: it is a bit wordy, which is not very good for nice magic :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to change type of Magic.charm to java.io.Serializable

you can write:

```
def hocusPocus(spells: Seq[String], charms: Seq[String]): Seq[Magic] = {
    for {
      spell <- spells
      charm <- if (charms.isEmpty) List(Option.empty) else charms
    } yield {
      new Magic(spell, charm)
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think `charms` will not be boxed into `Option` by default

Comment: but `charms.map(Some(_))` after `else` does the trick